# RXJS groupBy issues?

Tags: operators, rxjs

I need to do something with the RxJS groupBy operator and I try to understand how it works.

From the documentation's example:

```
const people = [{name: 'Sue', age:25},
{name: 'Joe', age: 30},
{name: 'Frank', age: 25}, 
{name: 'Sarah', age: 35}];

//Generate source from an array
const source = Rx.Observable.from(people);

//group by age
const example = source
.groupBy(person => person.age)
//accumulates
.mergeMap(group => group.reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, ...curr], []))
.subscribe(console.log);
```

the output is:

```
[{name: "Sue", age: 25}, {name: "Frank", age: 25}]

[{name: "Joe", age: 30}]

[{name: "Sarah", age: 35}]
```

I need something more "reactive", I mean, I get a infinite stream emitting values, and I need to buffer by time, then group the result. My code is similar to the previous one, but doesn't work

```
const subject = new Rx.Subject();

setInterval(() => {
  const rnd = Math.random();
  const person = rnd < 0.25 ? {name: 'Sue', age: 25} : (rnd > 0.25 && rnd < 0.50) ? {name: 'Joe', age: 30} : 'Sarah', age: 35};

//emits the generated value
subject.next(person);
}, 500);

subject.bufferTime(2000)
.mergeMap(x => Rx.Observable.from(x))
.groupBy(person => person.age)
.mergeMap(group => group.reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, ...curr], []))
.subscribe(console.log);
```

As you can see, only differs the generation code but I don't get nothing in my subscription.

this is the jsbin link: [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/beyorageya/edit?js,console)

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Use `scan` instead of `reduce`. The former will emit the accumulated array each time a value is received; the latter won't emit until the source completes.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `mergeMap` to inline your time-based buffered items into a single stream that stream never completes. This as result creates groups by using `groupBy` which never complete. As a result of this those groups will never emit to the mergeMap which reduce it all back to a single array.

To have your groupings complete you can append a `.take(XX)` to your source stream but this will not result in the behaviour you are looking for. All groups then complete when the original stream completes at the same time. This is very easy to spot with RxFiddle.net:

[image: RxFiddle stream visualisation]

Problems with this approach are:

- your groupings complete only when the stream completes
- the first grouping receives all values, the second all values from that point in time etcetera.

### How to complete your groupings on every window

To do so you have to do the groupings on every buffer/window value instead of the main stream. Then when the groupBy completes the `.reduce()` completes and your array will be emitted.

```js
Rx.Observable.interval(500)
  .map(i => Math.random())
  .map(rnd => rnd < 0.25 
       ? {name: 'Sue', age: 25} 
       : (rnd > 0.25 && rnd < 0.50)
         ? {name: 'Joe', age: 30} 
         : {name: 'Sarah', age: 35}
      )
  .window(Rx.Observable.interval(2000))
  .take(3)
  .mergeMap(x => {
    return x
      .groupBy(person => person.age)
      .mergeMap(group => group.reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr], []))
})
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val), err => console.log('err: ' + err));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.2.0/Rx.js"></script>
```

Few additional things to note:

- I have replaced your example `Subject` + `setInterval` with their Rx equivalent `Rx.Observable.interval` + map
- `window(windowBoundaries)` is equivalent to `bufferTime` but emits `Observable<T>` instead of `[]<T>` so you can remove the `Rx.Observable.from([]<T>)`
- `.reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr], [])` is equivalent to the [`.toArray()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-toArray) function available in RxJs

Comment: Then what is the solution to get the desired result?

Comment: @SergiDoteTeixidor sorry about my time-restrained answer. I have expanded on my original answer with an example. Hope this clears up your confusion and helps you get more grip on Rx coding

Comment: Thank you mate for you response!!